# Не работает звук у приложения, запущенного внутри chroot

Tags: linux, аудио, pulseaudio, chroot

Нужно проверить работоспособность одного приложения в чистом окружении.
Использую для этого chroot. Однако звук не воспроизводится :(

На хостовой машине запущен и исправно функционирует PulseAudio, как его
пробросить внутрь chroot-окружения? Прочитав [рекомендации из FAQ](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/FAQ/#index37h3) и мало
что поняв, попытался сделать вот так (целевой каталог обозначен как
`$new_root_path`, туда выполняется chroot, и там развёрнут Debian Unstable):

```sh
mkdir $new_root_path/tmp/myrundir
chmod 700 $new_root_path/tmp/myrundir
sudo mount --bind /var/lib/dbus $new_root_path/var/lib/dbus
sudo mount --bind $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR $new_root_path/tmp/myrundir
sudo mount --bind /dev/shm $new_root_path/dev/shm
sudo chroot $new_root_path su guest_user
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/myrundir
mplayer ...
```

UID пользователя внутри chroot совпадает с моим UID вне окружения. Внутри
chroot стоят пакеты `pulseaudio==10.0-1` и `dbus==1.10.18-1`, вне —
`pulseaudio==8.0-0ubuntu3.2` и `dbus==1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3`, их настройки не
менялись.

Итак, как мне запустить моё приложение (в примере MPlayer) в тестовом
окружении, чтоб оно смогло играть звук? При этом, не хотелось бы пробрасывать
все каталоги подряд внутрь клетки chroot, особенно домашний и для временных
файлов.

---

В каталоге `/var/lib/dbus` есть только одна ссылка `machine-id` на
`/etc/machine-id`. Внутри chroot она будет ссылаться на файл с другим
содержимым. Признаться честно, это меня смущает, но FAQ ничего не проясняет по
данному поводу... Как быть?

Comment: попробуйте действовать точно в соответствии с инструкцией, и запустите что-нибудь, чему доверяете. mplayer там какой-нибудь. если заработает, попробуйте монтировать меньше / более точечно (например, не /home, а /home/user/.pulse)

Comment: С той инструкцией проблема в том, что она делает слишком много лишних предположений. У меня в chroot домашние каталоги немного по-другому расположены, нету каталогов `~/.pulse`, `../unstable/run/user/1000` (значение `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` изначально равно `/run/user/1000`). Но даже если последний из них создать и попытаться последовательно выполнить указанные там команды mount, то ничего не заработает. Вывод: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24775553/

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, стоит отметить, что если запускать mplayer вне chroot, то также ругается на _"Failed to open LIRC support"_. Однако воспроизведение работает.

Comment: *AO: [pulse] Init failed: Connection refused* — вот с этим и надо разбираться. а потом уже «урезать» монтируемое. (про lirc mplayer всегда жалуется. это где-то в конфигурации можно отключить, или не обращать внимание).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, кажется, разобрался. Та инструкция какая-то странная... В моём случае же
достаточно было лишь пробросить сокет `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse/native` и блоки
разделяемой памяти `/dev/shm` внутрь окружения chroot, а также установить
переменную окружения **PULSE_SERVER** с адресом сокета. Например, так:

```sh
mkdir $new_root_path/tmp/pulse_d
sudo mount --bind $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse $new_root_path/tmp/pulse_d
sudo mount --bind /dev/shm $new_root_path/dev/shm
sudo chroot $new_root_path
export PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/pulse_d/native
mplayer ...
```

Если вы пытаетесь запускать программы в chroot-клетке под другим
пользователем, может понадобиться дать доступ к X серверу вне chroot (зачем —
не знаю, такое вообще не рекомендуется, если сервер PulseAudio запущен не в
системном режиме).

```sh
xhost +
```

Хорошая новость: наличие установленного пакета pulseaudio внутри chroot
необязательно.

Предостережение: если вы не меняли настройки сервера PulseAudio и используется
Unix сокет, то по умолчанию он создаётся в каталоге `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse`,
но только если не установлена переменная окружения **PULSE_RUNTIME_DIR** при
запуске сервера. В качестве запасного варианта сокет может создаваться во
временной папке `/tmp`.

Файлы разделяемой памяти приходится делать доступными, если PulseAudio их
использует. Это задаётся при запуске, и в Ubuntu 16.04 по умолчанию как раз
так.